# getting time difference between a date and current date using moment

Tags: javascript, datetime, react-native, momentjs

Hi I am trying to get the time difference between two dates. I have written a function which does this but when I convert the passed in date from shared preferences to moment date it gives me single digit number.

Using this in my react native project

I tried the same with manual input dates as string and it works fine.

what am I doing wrong here?

//This function does not work as expected (I want this function to return the time difference)

```
export const getTimeDiffWithCurrentTime = (lastLoggedInDateTime) => {
  var moment = require('moment');
//***PROBLEM IS HERE IN THE BELLOW LINE WHERE THE OUTPUT IS 1547571895000***
  var momentLastLoggedInDateTime = moment(lastLoggedInDateTime, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
  var currentDateTime = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
  consoleLog(' lastLoggedInDateTime - ' + lastLoggedInDateTime + 'momentLastLoggedInDateTime - ' + momentLastLoggedInDateTime
    + ' currentDateTime - ' + currentDateTime);
  var timeDifference = currentDateTime.diff(momentLastLoggedInDateTime);
  consoleLog("Time difference - " + timeDifference);
  return timeDifference;
}
```

output : 
`lastLoggedInDateTime - 15-01-2019 17:04:55momentLastLoggedInDateTime - 1547571895000 currentDateTime - 15-01-2019 17:04:57`

`error -TypeError: currentDateTime.diff is not a function`

Test Function that works

```
export const getTimeDiff = () => {
  var moment = require('moment');
  var now  = moment("04-09-2013 15:00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
  var then = moment("04-09-2013 14:59:40", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
  var timeDifference = now.diff(then);
  consoleLog("Time difference - " + timeDifference);
}
```

output : 
`Time difference - 20000`

I want to get the function `getTimeDiffWithCurrentTime` to work by passing a date and get the difference.

your help is much appreciated

R

UPDATE

Got it working. Few things to note.

Some have suggested to just use `var momentLastLoggedInDateTime = moment(lastLoggedInDateTime);`

but that gave me a warning similar to

`Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info. Arguments: [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _useUTC: true, _l: undefined, _i: 2016-9-26 19:30, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]`

So I had to use `var momentLastLoggedInDateTime = moment(lastLoggedInDateTime, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");`

which gave me a value `1547571895000`

Only change I had to make to the function 'getTimeDiffWithCurrentTime' was to change `var currentDateTime = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");` to `var currentDateTime = moment();`

so the working function is

```
export const getTimeDiffWithCurrentTime = (lastLoggedInDateTime) => {
  var moment = require('moment');
  var momentLastLoggedInDateTime = moment(lastLoggedInDateTime, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
  var currentDateTime = moment(); //This was the change required
  consoleLog(' lastLoggedInDateTime - ' + lastLoggedInDateTime + 'momentLastLoggedInDateTime - ' + momentLastLoggedInDateTime
    + ' currentDateTime - ' + currentDateTime);
  var timeDifference = currentDateTime.diff(momentLastLoggedInDateTime);
  consoleLog("Time difference - " + timeDifference);
  return timeDifference;
}
```

Output

`lastLoggedInDateTime - 15-01-2019 18:12:26momentLastLoggedInDateTime - 1547575946000 currentDateTime - 1547575952574`
`Time difference - 6574`

Thank you

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: @JeffUK I want to get the first function to work sorry that is not that clear I will update it

Answer (score 1):

according to the [documentation of moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/), basically with no parameters, the `diff` function returns a number in `milliseconds`, you can use `years`, `months`, `weeks`, `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds` if you want to use a different time unit.

take into account:

> By default, moment#diff will truncate the result to zero decimal places, returning an integer. If you want a floating point number, pass true as the third argument.

check a working piece of code which shows other types of units.

```js
const getTimeDiff = (differenceIn = 'milliseconds', floating= false) => {
  var now = moment("04-09-2013 15:00:00", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
  var then = moment("04-09-2013 14:59:40", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
  //this return the difference between now and then in milliseconds as default
  var timeDifference = now.diff(then, differenceIn, floating);
  console.log("Time difference - " + timeDifference + ' ' + differenceIn);
}

getTimeDiff();
getTimeDiff('seconds');
getTimeDiff('seconds', true);
getTimeDiff('minutes');
getTimeDiff('minutes', true);
getTimeDiff('hours');
getTimeDiff('hours', true);
getTimeDiff('days');
getTimeDiff('days', true);
getTimeDiff('weeks');
getTimeDiff('weeks', true);
getTimeDiff('months');
getTimeDiff('months', true);
getTimeDiff('years');
getTimeDiff('years', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.js"></script>
```

On your code, check that you are trying to do a `diff` of a `String`.
Basically you are doing a `format` before applying the `diff`.

```js
const getTimeDiffWithCurrentTime = (lastLoggedInDateTime) => {
  //***PROBLEM IS HERE IN THE BELLOW LINE WHERE THE OUTPUT IS 1547571895000***
  var momentLastLoggedInDateTime = moment(lastLoggedInDateTime, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
  //var currentDateTime = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"); IF YOU DO THIS, you get a STRING
  var currentDateTime = moment()
  console.log(' lastLoggedInDateTime - ' + lastLoggedInDateTime + 'momentLastLoggedInDateTime - ' + momentLastLoggedInDateTime +
    ' currentDateTime - ' + currentDateTime);
  var timeDifference = currentDateTime.diff(momentLastLoggedInDateTime);
  console.log("Time difference - " + timeDifference);
  return timeDifference;
}

const newDate = new Date(new Date() - 10000); //minus 10 seconds


getTimeDiffWithCurrentTime(newDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: And that is what I tried before and then as per documentation i converted from `var momentLastLoggedInDateTime = moment(lastLoggedInDateTime);` to `var momentLastLoggedInDateTime = moment(lastLoggedInDateTime, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: @BRDroid using that formatting on the constructor works, because `moment(date, format)` is returning an `Moment Date`, but if you take a `Moment Date` and apply `format` you will get a `string`.
check the answer, I edited it to have the format on the `constructor`, but still you need to remove format.
Only use `format` when you want to display//save//send the date in a proper way.

Comment: @BRDroid did you check my answer and comment?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var now  = moment(new Date());
var then = moment("04-09-2013 14:59:40", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
var timeDifferenceInSeconds = now.diff(then, 'seconds');
var timeDifferenceInHours = now.diff(then, 'hours');
var timeDifferenceInDay = now.diff(then, 'days');
console.log(timeDifferenceInHours, timeDifferenceInSeconds, timeDifferenceInDay);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello @Avanthika I wanted the the function `getTimeDiffWithCurrentTime` to work